# How do you unbind only some events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few things like this...

`$('body').on('keyup', function(e){if(e.which === 32){//do stuff}})`

I need to disable some of these events at times but not all of them.

`$('body').off('keyup')` just turns them all off.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Namespace them...

```
$('body').on('keyup.some_name', function(e){if(e.which === 32){//do stuff}})
```

---

```
$('body').off('keyup.some_name')
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var onKeyUp = function(e){if(e.which === 32){//do stuff}}

$('body').on('keyup', onKeyUp);

// later...

$('body').off('keyup', onKeyUp);
```